# How to convert content inside a div into an image for social media sharing?

Tags: javascript, html

How can one create something like Facebook Badges? What sort of technologies are involved? Can it be done using purely JavaScript? If I have a `div` with some content inside it, how do I convert that into an image for sharing purposes?

Also see what Medium is doing with their new sharing feature: https://twitter.com/Medium/status/620651949529112576. As you select the text, it generates a graphic for sharing that contains the selected text.

Comment: Refer [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). This will let you create `canvas` from a `div`. Contents of canvas can be converted to image using [`toDataURL()`](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-url/)

Comment: @ShrinivasShukla - Why can't I get the `toDataURL` to work? I've been playing around with it here. I get an error in the console. http://jsfiddle.net/b7wgoL73/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have placed the following code outside the `function onrendered()`.

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
console.log(dataURL);
```

Due to which it gets executed before the `canvas` is even rendered.

Place this code inside `onrendered()`.

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/b7wgoL73/1/).

Here is the snippet.

```js
function testScrnShot() {
  html2canvas(document.getElementById("testing"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
      console.log(dataURL);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#testing {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 1em;
}
canvas {
  float: right;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/download/0.5.0-alpha1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<div id="testing" onclick="testScrnShot();"><strong>Hello</strong>, this is a test</div>
```

Prints the `data url` in the console now.

Comment: Thanks for the fix! In order to convert the dataURL to a proper URL, it would need to be hosted? Or is dataURL shareable on social media?

Comment: Just put the `data url` in the address bar of the browser, it renders image. If you want to share the image directly, then you can share this `data url` as well.

Comment: It is a good practice to "Accept" and "Upvote" the helpful answer as it help everyone who visits this question in future.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Yes I checked it in the browser and it renders fine. Was just trying to think how to "prettify" it, I guess.